# How do I create local variable to track an ID that will output whether it was first payment

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Been working on this project for a week and feel I'm getting closer. Created a PL/SQL block that will output a donor's specific pledge, number of payments, pay date and pay amount I've got most of it done and it compiles and produces desired output with exception of handling whether or not it was the first payment on the corresponding row. How can i create a variable to track this and then test it within the block and not bugger up what I've go already. Here is a sample of the output I get now and my PLSQL code. Thanks!

Pledge ID: 106 Pledge Amount: $75 Monthly Payment: $0 Pay Date:12-OCT-12Amount Paid: $75
Pledge ID: 109 Pledge Amount: $360 Monthly Payment: $12 Pay Date: 01-FEB-13 Amount Paid: $30
Pledge ID: 109 Pledge Amount: $360 Monthly Payment: $12 Pay Date: 01-MAR-13 Amount Paid: $30

As you can see 'First Payment' should be displayed on the first two rows.

My Code:

```
DECLARE
pledge_id   DD_PLEDGE.idpledge%TYPE;
pledge_amt  DD_PLEDGE.pledgeamt%TYPE;
pay_months  DD_PLEDGE.paymonths%TYPE;
pay_date    DD_PAYMENT.paydate%TYPE;
pay_amt     DD_PAYMENT.payamt%TYPE;
donor_id    DD_PLEDGE.iddonor%TYPE; 

CURSOR cur_pledges IS
SELECT pl.idpledge, pl.pledgeamt, pl.paymonths, pay.paydate,  
pay.payamt, pl.iddonor FROM DD_PLEDGE pl JOIN DD_PAYMENT pay ON
pl.idpledge = pay.idpledge
WHERE pl.iddonor = 301
ORDER BY pl.idpledge, pay.paydate; 

BEGIN
OPEN cur_pledges;
LOOP
FETCH cur_pledges INTO pledge_id, pledge_amt, pay_months, pay_date,   
pay_amt, donor_id;

--possible test here for first payment

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Pledge ID: ' || pledge_id || ' Pledge Amount: $' 
|| pledge_amt || ' Monthly Payment: $' || pay_months 
|| ' Pay Date: ' || pay_date || ' Amount Paid: $' || pay_amt);

EXIT WHEN cur_pledges%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_pledges;
END;
```

Comment: Can you try this - If  cur_pledges%ROWCOUNT = 1 then dbms_output.put_line('first payment');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly.
You are trying to find out first payment done by a `donorid` .
Then Use %ROWCOUNT in a cursor to find out how many rows are there for that donor.if more than one row then it is not his first payment else first payment

```
DECLARE
pledge_id   DD_PLEDGE.idpledge%TYPE;
pledge_amt  DD_PLEDGE.pledgeamt%TYPE;
pay_months  DD_PLEDGE.paymonths%TYPE;
pay_date    DD_PLEDGE.paydate%TYPE;
pay_amt     DD_PLEDGE.payamt%TYPE;
donor_id    DD_PLEDGE.iddonor%TYPE; 
First_pay_flag varchar2(10); --Just set a flag

CURSOR cur_pledges IS
SELECT pl.idpledge, pl.pledgeamt, pl.paymonths, pl.paydate,payamt,iddonor
from DD_PLEDGE pl    WHERE pl.iddonor = 007
ORDER BY pl.idpledge, pl.paydate; 

BEGIN
OPEN cur_pledges;
LOOP
FETCH cur_pledges INTO pledge_id, pledge_amt, pay_months, pay_date,pay_amt, donor_id;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Pledge ID: ' || pledge_id || ' Pledge Amount: $' 
|| pledge_amt || ' Monthly Payment: $' || pay_months 
|| ' Pay Date: ' || pay_date || ' Amount Paid: $' || pay_amt);

IF CUR_PLEDGES%ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First payment');
First_pay_flag := 'YES';
Else
-- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not the first payment.');
First_pay_flag  :='NO';
END IF;

EXIT WHEN cur_pledges%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_pledges;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(10)||chr(13) || 'Is this a first payment ? ' || First_pay_flag   );

END;
```

[image: OUTPUT]

P.S. I have created single table. Change them

Comment: I apologize it has taken me this long to respond. your method works in a different way. Pledge ID is the variable but can be applied the same way. I'm still leaning toward using a local variable to keep track of the PledgeID. If it is '1' then wouldn't that be first payment? I want to try your method first.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: how pledge_id is assigned values? I suppose you are using a sequence to generate values for pledge_id (ie., incrementing) if so I am afraid that it won't work, as Pledge id for a donor will keep increasing as and when he keeps making payments

Comment: Mahendar, you were correct. This must be done with the iddonor. Changed a couple blocks you provided and I'm getting the results I wanted. Much appreciated. Beginner here and will definitely be looking for more help with future projects. Allen